# Django and File Permissions: Best Practices?

Tags: python, django

I am integrating "legacy" code with Django, and have problems when the process executing Django must write to legacy code directories where it lacks write permissions.  (The legacy code is a Python backend to a Tkinter GUI, which I'm repurposing to a browser-based UI.)

I could:

- Make the legacy directory writeable
  to all, but this seems like bad
  practice.
- Find the userid of the Django
  execution process, assign that to a
  group and give that group write
  permissions to the whole legacy
  directory.  (I suspect this is the
  user running apache.)  This too seems
  bad -- if that user is
  compromised,the whole directory is at
  risk.
- Isolate the "write" calls in the
  code, ensure they all go somewhere in
  a designated subdirectory tree, and
  make that tree world (or Django user
  group) writeable.  This seems the
  least risky, but also the most work.

Any other ideas?  Am I missing some obvious fix?  I'm completely new to this.

Answer (score 0):

I'd go with option number 2.  I don't think your django user is any more likely to get compromised than your Tkinter user.  If there's something else under apache that you're worried about, run it under a separate apache with the right user.